# Custom pagination using jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am new to javascript and jquery. Currently I am using the jquery data-table in my project. I am getting the json data from server using ajax to display the data. The server is sending huge number of records and it is implemented by other team and hence they cannot do the server side pagination for me. I am planning to write custom pagination on the client side but not sure if jquery-datatable allows me to do this.

1. Can we override the jquery-datatable to handle next, previous buttons and get the next set of data using ajax ourselves?
2. Can we also override the default filter search on the table to search on the server to get the data.

If possible, please let me know how to implement this in jquery.

Comment: if you're new to javascript and jquery, then I would advise to read up books and documentation and really get familiarized with it. Asking on SO will give you solutions, not experience. Learn by reading and doing by yourself!

Comment: I have seen the documentation of jquery-datatables but did not find references regarding overriding the pagination logic.

Comment: Do you mean DataTables? As in http://datatables.net? There are a whole bunch of examples for doing what you're doing on that site. There is also a forum there, and for a small donation you can get some great support from the author.

Comment: Look at http://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/, all examples of pagination plugins